# jQuery UI droppable "out" event doesn't trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable, out

On "over"-ing I'm rebuilding the droppable elements by $(this).parent.empty().append(...)
(they basically consist of `<li>` elements)

The problem is that the actual element, awaiting the "out" function to be triggered is deleted as well --> out cannot be fired

is there any solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried .live. This will add it back on if you create the elements after the DOM has been loaded already. So if you have some thing like $("#mylist li").live('handler', function(){}); Im not sure exactly what you are doing, but it would be something like this.

You can see some examples here:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

And in face you can do multiple handlers.

```
$("#mylist li").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

Delegate as Husky suggested:

```
$("#mylist").delegate("li", "mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

Comment: You should avoid using `live`, it's very resource hungry. Instead of `live`, try `delegate`, which can be binded to the element that will receive the bubbling events.

Comment: @Husky i haven't used delegate before, so i didn't want to give the wrong code, but you are right. It does look to be more efficient since it doesn't search the entire DOM. I updated my answer, let me know if that's incorrect. Thanks!